# MX record pointing to different subdomains

Tags: domain-name-system, email-server, mx-record

Is it possible to have multiple email MX records for subdomains ?
eg:
domain: xyz.com - MX - Heartinternet emails
o365.xyz.com - MX - Office 365
gsuit.xyz.com - MX - Google

In this case do we have to update SPF record for xyz.com allowing all the email providers ?

Answer (score 0):

The MX record tells email senders where to send email bound to a specific domain or subdomain. If you have that need, there's nothing preventing you from hosting the email for different domains with different service providers.

SPF records should be set up for each mail-enabled sub domain. And don't forget DKIM and DMARC to enhance your sender reputation.

Comment: SPF/DKIM/DMARC/BIMI are related to when the domain sends emails (more precisely when sending emails with addresses on those domains), shouldn't be related to when receiving emails.

Comment: Sorry, yes, I didn't think to add that, but that's entirely correct.